# Why would you use .net Cache when there is a disk Cache?

Tags: .net, windows, caching

In .Net there is the Cache API that helps you to cache file in memory (with the fileDependancy). But there is also a disk cache managed by the OS that is suppsoed to do the same thing.

Why would I use one instead the other ?

Comment: You are thinking too small... Let's say that you don't simply need to load a file in memory... You need to load a file in memory, do some big (slow) operations on it and cache the result of these operations... clearly if the file changes, you have to redo everything. Windows cache will only cache the original file, not the "transformed" object. The various .NET caches will cache the "transformed" object.

Comment: And even in the simplest case, going through the filesystem (something you need to do to access a file, even if the Windows Cache contains fully it) is **slow**. Accessing a "local" object is much faster.

Comment: @xanatos I'm already using the Cache for this kind of thing, I was just curious to know if my caching of disk file is usefull or if I just have to increase my disk cache

Comment: benchmark benchmark benchmark :-) It is difficult to give absolute responses.